# Is it safe to use getElementByID and querySelectorAll without DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am just wondering will I get consistent results if I use `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelectorAll` within `DOMContentLoaded` event listener and outside of it.

I was searching the web and couldn't find a topic similar to this.

I was also reading the [w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/) and couldn't find anything mentioning this.

I am not asking about a situation where I get `null` or an empty `NodeList`, but imagine this scenario:

On a page you have this element

```
<div id="el"></div>
```

and in JS you have these

```
let id = document.getElementById('el');
let qs = document.querySelectorAll('#el');
```

Now the question is, will I get a positive match (`id !== null` and `qs.length > 0`) in every browser (except IE <=8) every time? Or is there a scenario where these could not find the element `#el`?

Has anyone had any problems using this in production environments?

Comment: it just depends on how you place your scripts on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can search these API in the “https://caniuse.com”. you can see which browser supported these API. If you are looking for the existence of a single element, it is recommended to use "querySelector".